# pandas to_sql if_exists='appned'

Tags: database, pandas

I have a data frame and would like to insert it into an existing table in ms database. Below is the code I use:

```
df = pd.read_csv(f, engine='c', encoding='utf-8')
df.to_sql('dbo.pb', engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Unfortunately, the 'append' does not work as the document described. I had to use a new table name in to_sql to put the data into a new table. 
Do I misunderstand anything here? How can the  parameter'append' work? Thanks for you help in advance!

I was working on Explore Anaconda 2 Jupyter notebook.

Comment: `Unfortunately, the 'append' does not work as the document described` - could you be more specific? How did it work and what did you expect?